# Mock aspect in junit failed to apply

Tags: maven, junit, aspectj

I'm building up a simple project to learn aspectj.

It's from aspect in action 2nd and the idea is very simple ---- the `MessageCommunicator` will be responsible for delivering the message and it's the main business logic. Meanwhile, `Authenticator` will be responsible for authentication and will be weaved as declared `SecurityAspect`.

Though it's very straightforward to see in the log that the aspect is working. Still I want to ensure it works in junit case.

In my project, I'm using maven 3.0.4 with aspectj 1.7.3 and aspect-maven-plugin 1.5.

Now the problem is below warning is there when compile the test case. As the consequence, the aspects in test package doesn't work. However, if you write a Main class in source package and run, the aspect in source package will work.

The warning message while build:

```
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.5:test-compile (test-compile_with_aspectj) @ aspectj ---
[WARNING] advice defined in org.javen.study.aspectj.c02.aspects.MockAuthenticationAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.javen.study.aspectj.c02.aspects.SecurityAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.javen.study.aspectj.c02.aspects.TrackingAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

I will also attach all the related source code below:
`MessageCommunicator` who is responsible for the main business:

```
package org.javen.study.aspectj.c02;

public class MessageCommunicator {
    public void deliver(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public void deliver(String person, String message) {
        System.out.println(person + ", " + message);
    }
}
```

Simple version of authenticator which will do the authentication:

```
public class Authenticator {

    public void authenticate() {
        System.out.println("authenticated");
    }
}
```

`SecurityAspect` which will advice on `MessageCommunicator`:

```
package org.javen.study.aspectj.c02.aspects;

import org.javen.study.aspectj.c02.Authenticator;

public aspect SecurityAspect {
    private Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();

    declare warning 
        : call(void Authenticator.authenticate()) 
            && !within(SecurityAspect)
        : "Authentication should be performed only by SecurityAspect";

    pointcut secureAccess() : execution(* org.javen.study.aspectj.c02.MessageCommunicator.deliver(..));

    before() : secureAccess() {
        System.out.println("Checking and authenticating user");
        authenticator.authenticate();
    }
}
```

`MockAuthenticationAspect` in test package to advice the authenticator to inject some verification logic(no need to look into advice detail, the advice implementation is problematic):

```
package org.javen.study.aspectj.c02.aspects;
import org.javen.study.aspectj.c02.Authenticator;

public aspect MockAuthenticationAspect {
    declare parents: Authenticator implements Callable;
    private boolean Callable.isCalled;

    public void Callable.call() {
        isCalled = true;
    }

    public boolean Callable.isCalled() {
        return isCalled;
    }

    Object around(Callable accessTracked)   : execution(* Authenticator.authenticate(..)) 
        && !execution(* Callable.*(..)) 
        && this(accessTracked) {
        accessTracked.call();
        return null;
    }

    private static interface Callable {
    }
}
```

The pom of whole project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.javen.study</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.3</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*.aj</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile_with_aspectj</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile_with_aspectj</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When build with command "mvn clean install", the warning texts will be printed and the test package advice will not work. However, if check with AJDT in eclipse, all the pointcut and advice is working.

Could someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by added below configuration in test-compile execution.

```
<execution>
    <id>test-compile_with_aspectj</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>test-compile</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <weaveDirectories>
            <weaveDirectory>target/classes</weaveDirectory>
        </weaveDirectories>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Don't know it's a good pratice or not, but at least now it works.